# Fragment replacing does not work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got a BottomMenu which works properly. The Problem is if I want to switch from one of those menu Fragments via Buttonclick into a new Fragment(switchtoallstudies() Method) it will just switch to a blank space.
How can I fix this?

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;
private AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;
private NoSwipePager viewPager;
private BottomBarAdapter pagerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    setupViewPager();

    bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    addBottomNavigationItems();
    setBottomNavigationStyle();

    bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(0);

    bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTabSelected (int position, boolean wasSelected) {
            if (!wasSelected)
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            return true;
        }
    });

}

public void switchtoallstudies(){
    //getAlllStudies
    Frag_alle_studien fragallestudien = new Frag_alle_studien();

    //start up fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragdashcontainer, fragallestudien).commit();
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    viewPager = (NoSwipePager) findViewById(R.id.fragdashcontainer);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    pagerAdapter = new BottomBarAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pagerAdapter.addFragments(new Frag_Startseite());
    pagerAdapter.addFragments(new Frag_Frageboegen());
    pagerAdapter.addFragments(new Frag_Studien());
    pagerAdapter.addFragments(new Frag_Ergebnisse());
    pagerAdapter.addFragments(new Frag_Einstellungen());

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: where do you implement the button click listener and are there any views on your AllStudiesFragment?

Comment: the Button is in "Frag_Studien", and yes I implemented views and they are working correctly..... I do know that because for testing I just added: 
"pagerAdapter.addFragment(new Frag_alle_studien());" and called it in switchtoallStudies with "viewPager.setCurrentItem(5);"
But thats not how its supposed to work cause the pageradapter is actually just for the Bottom navigation

Comment: please post the button logic here because the method seems right, the problem I think in your onclikc listener

Comment: The Button Listener just contains:

((Dashboard) getActivity()).switchtoallstudies();

Comment: ok, looks fine, the docs also warn developers to use FrameLayout for fragment replacement , is your fragdashcontainer a framelayolut? It can lead to some issues with view.

Comment: nope my container is a viewpager 
Btw I used this BottomMenu [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/ultimate-guide-to-bottom-navigation-on-android-75e4efb8105f)
maybe it will help coming up with a solution

Comment: Added the full answer, it seems we've found the problem with the layout design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provided in comments the layout xml contains FrameLayout

see code

And it's also said in the article

> The FrameLayout with ID @+id/frame is the placeholder UI to load our
>   Fragment.

**Read your article from the link again!**

It's recommended to always use a framelayout as a container to replace fragments. If you don't want to change your code drastically you can try adding FrameLayout inside ViewPager with the same size. But if it still doesn't work, I believe the right way to do this would be to get rid of your viewpager and just replace the fragments onbottommenu click inside your framelayolut container. Here is link to a great **working** [article](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0). I used it myself .

Comment: Maybe someone else can suggest a solution, it not , use my link . It works for sure

Comment: Couldnt find a proper solution ...
So now I am using support Library like in the article you provided and it works just fine. Thanks :)